# Format string in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, string

How can i format a string like "Fri Oct 17 00:00:00 +0200 2003" to a simple date string like Fri Oct 17 2003?

Is there any easy solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, use the `NSDateFormatter` to parse the first into an NSDate and then use another `NSDateFormatter` to write out that `NSDate` in the second format.

Comment: Or the same `NSDateFormatter` with it's `dateFormat` changed.

Comment: But how to handle "+0200"? Something like this?

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM d hh:mm:ss +0200 YYYY"];

Comment: Ok, this works for me:

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM d hh:mm:ss ZZZ YYYY"];

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can find a list of the date format specifiers here: [Unicode Date Formats](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: FINALLY i've been searching for this for 15 minutes :)
Thanks